# Calling a template conditionally xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

first post so hopefully someone could help out. Basically, I am outputting a pdf via an xslt and my issue is that I have a table that I only want generated if that table contains content. I believe my call-template always initiates and therefore always at least brings back a table header row even if there is no content. I do not want the table to appear at all. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="http://www.appian.com/ae/types/2009">

          <div id="processVariables">
      <xsl:call-template name="applicantDetails"  />
      </div>
      <xsl:call-template name="pp" />
      <xsl:call-template name="processMilestoneList" />
      <xsl:call-template name="processCommentList" />
    </div>
    <div id="pageFooter" />
  </body>
</html>
```

```
    <xsl:template name="processCommentList"> 
<div id="processCommentList"> 
<th space-before ="12pt" keep-with-next="always" font-weight="bold">Process comments:</th>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th id="date">Date</th>
    <th id="user">User</th>
    <th id="comment">Comment</th>
  </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="//processCommentList/item">
      <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:call-template name="DisplayDate">
             <xsl:with-param name="dateString">
             <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
             </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </td>
        <td>
        <xsl:variable name="commentUser">
          <xsl:value-of select="user"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:value-of select="//a:processManifest/a:processUserList/a:User[username/@a:id=$commentUser]/fullName/text()"/>
        </td>
        <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="comment" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:if test="//processCommentList/item">
    <xsl:call-template name="processCommentList"/>
</xsl:if>
```

This test will fail if there is no //processCommentList/item and, therefore, not call the template.

If processCommentList is absent if empty, you can also do the more recursive thing of:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//processCommentList"/>
<xsl:template match="processCommentList[count(item)]>
    <table>...etc
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
    </table> ... etc
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="item">
    <tr>...etc...</tr>
</xsl:template>
```